# Laravel order by hasmany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two eloquent models `Threads` and `Comments` , each thread hasMany comments.

While listing the threads, i need to order the threads by the created_at descending. So , i need to sort the threads using `created at` in `Comments`.

Apparently dot notation isn't helpful in ordering this way, how do i order the Threads correctly ?

```
$Threads= Thread::all()->orderBy("comment.created_at","desc")
```

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The orderBy , apparently dotted notation doesn't wok in orderBy("comments.created_at"."desc")

Comment: How would you like to sort it? One thread have comment from 1.01.2014 and 1.03.2014, and the second one has threads from 2.01.2015 and 2.02.2015 - which one should be first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand how Laravel's eager loading works.  If we eager load your example, Laravel first fetches all threads.  Then it fetches all comments and adds them to the threads object.  Since separate queries are used, it isn't possible to order threads by comments.

You need to use a join instead.  Note that I'm guessing at your table/column names in this example.

```
$threads = Thread::leftJoin('comment', 'comment.thread_id', '=', 'thread.id')
    ->with('comments')
    ->orderBy('comment.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Since you're joining, you might need to manually specify columns to select your tables column names.

```
$threads = Thread::select('thread.*')->leftJoin('comment', 'comment.thread_id', '=', 'thread.id')
    ->with('comments')
    ->orderBy('comment.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I don't think eager loading is necessary here if we just want to sort threads by most recent comment (not actually display comments).  Also since this is a hasMany relationship, threads with more than one comment will appear more than once in the results which is probably not what we want. When working with hasMany, should also add in a groupBy clause like so: `groupBy('thread.id')` to prevent such duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function profiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Models\v1\Admin\UserProfile', 'user_id')->leftJoin('user_field', 'user_profile.user_field_id', '=', 'user_field.id')->orderBy('order');
}
```

Comment: Note that a groupBy clause should also be used, to prevent duplicates, when working with a hasMany relationship.