# Laravel: Order By hasMany relationship's first (oldest) entry

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following tables:

`PRODUCTS
id | title
-- | ---------------
1  | First Product
2  | Second Product
3  | Third Product`

PRODUCT_VERSIONS
id | product_id | release_date
-- | ---------- | ------------
1  | 1          | 2013-01-01
2  | 1          | 2014-01-01
3  | 1          | 2015-03-01
4  | 2          | 2013-02-02
5  | 2          | 2014-02-02
6  | 2          | 2015-02-02
7  | 3          | 2013-03-03
8  | 3          | 2014-03-03
9  | 3          | 2015-03-03

---

**Relationships**

Product->hasMany("ProductVersion")

ProductVersion->belongsTo("Product")

---

**What I want to do is select all products and order by the first (oldest) product_version.release_date.**

Or maybe it's better to sort the product_versions by release_date, group by addon_id and then join the product table?

I have searched and searched for a solution, and I have a couple queries that almost work. I'm wondering if there is an easy(ish) way of doing this with Laravel.

Comment: I think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143061/laravel-orderby-on-a-relationship) may be what you're looking for. Check out the comments to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel order by hasmany relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634921/laravel-order-by-hasmany-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins for this. Join the two tables, group them by id, order by the latest date, which I aliased as "latest_release_date":

```
$products = Product::selectRaw('products.*, MAX(product_versions.release_date) as latest_release_date')
    ->leftJoin('product_versions', 'product_versions.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->orderBy('latest_release_date', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

You mentioned grouping by `addon_id`, but it's not shown anywhere on your table examples so I just used names from the table examples you provided.